# Would an android device pass the boot screen/enter recovery without build.prop?

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, stock-android

Is it possible to start up an android device without build.prop? Is it even possible to use stock recovery without build.prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can boot into recovery without build.prop. You can, in fact, boot into recovery without anything in /system (actually, recovery and bootloader are the only things you can boot into without anything in your /system.); build.prop and /system are only used when the ROM is loaded.